# How to insert column value in string?

Tags: python, postgresql

How to insert column value in string (postgres, python)

```
select * from table where title ~* '\y(?:ROW_VALUE_HERE)\y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation operator `||`

```sql
select * from table where title ~* '\y(?:' || my_column || ')\y';
```

or `format` function:

```sql
select * from table where title ~* format('\y(?:%s)\y', my_column)';
```